# How to disable the "featured image" on buddyboss theme wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, buddyboss

What I'm struggling to achieve is not to disable the "featured image" completely, because I need the thumbnail while sharing the link. I'm just trying not to let it appear on posts. I know how to hide it using CSS, but I'd like not to let it to load it either to prevent an extra page's load time.

I'm using BuddyBoss theme 2.0.3 on WordPress.

Here's a sample post which the huge featured image appears on it and it's not really necessary and beautiful: [farsi.pro/test/persian-level-test-free](https://farsi.pro/test/persian-level-test-free/)

Thanks for any kind help or clue!

Comment: create a child theme and change the post template, deleting the part of the code which contains the thumbnail image